# How do I capture the Menu Clicks in GTM in a manner that indicates the hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Please I really need help creating a custom javascript variable in GTM that will capture Menu click text in a hierarchical manner.

So for example, when I hover over the "About" tab in my Menu, other buttons show up under it titled "About CEO" and "History". When I click on "About CEO" I want the variable to capture "About: About CEO" and when I click on History I want the variable to capture "About: History". Finally when I click on only About I want the variable to capture "About".

I've been able to find the right CSS selector for the Menu div but I'm not great with javascript. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sample dropdown menu HTML -

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">About</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/aboutceo">About CEO</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/history">History</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set up click trigger in GTM by class name -

[image]

GTM custom javascript code -

```
function() {
   var elm = {{Click Element}};
   var clickText = elm.textContent;
   return elm.closest('div.dropdown').getElementsByClassName('dropbtn')[0].innerHTML +' : '+ clickText;
}
```

output in Google Analytics -

[image]